# 'fileExists' produces 'Bool', not the expected contextual result type 'Bool'

Tags: swift, nsfilemanager

This line of code:

```
if !FileManager.fileExists(atPath: documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("newname.pdf"))
```

is getting an error saying

> 'fileExists' produces 'Bool', not the expected contextual result type
>   'Bool'

on Xcode 9.2. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `fileExists` on an instance of a `FileManager`. It's not a class method.

`FileManager` provides the `default` instance that is used in most cases.

```
if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("newname.pdf"))
```